# joomla freeze when install it?

Tags: php, sql, apache, joomla, xampp

i am trying to install joomla but it freezes , i used XAMP and i tried a lot of solutions , but they didn't help , and the problem still the same , i changed the xamp\htdoc\my joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql  and i opened Joomla.sql file and replace the term  "ENGINE=InnoDB" with "ENGINE=MyIsam" ,but didn't help me .
i also tried the following :
in php.ini file i made both output_buffering and display_errors equal to off

```
Output_Buffering=Off 
Display_Errors=Off
```

and in xamp\htdoc\my joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql\Joomla.sql
replaced all the occurence of "ENGINE=InnoDB" with "ENGINE=MyIsam"

please help :( ,i tried several answers on a question similar to mine but the difference was that they uses WAMP server while i used XAMP , but they didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser like Chrome or Firefox and check the developer console (F12 in Chrome) for any errors coming from the AJAX request being made in background.

There is no need to hack installation files. It is important to understand what the error is and when does it occur.